# Develop an application on 2 different machine

Tags: python, django

I would like to develop a web application (Django 1.11, python 2.7) on 2 different machines: the morning developping on a computer and the evening on another computer. currently I copy the entire folder from one machine to another
Is there another way?

Comment: You can use version control such as [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

Comment: You can use any version control system (git, github, bitbucket, etc)

Comment: Use and version control like git, bitbucket or svn

Answer (score 1):

You can use a version control software to do so. 
[Here](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/version-control-software/) are 15 best software to do the job.

Using these you can push your code from one machine and take the latest pull on another machine and start working from where you left  and then push it again